# Start rails server from python script

Tags: python, ruby-on-rails

I have written a rails app for a friends college project on a Raspberry pi, using thin server gem. The app logs temperatures and reads limits back to a python script that runs on boot up. This python code then controls servos and lights to heat/cool rooms in a model house. 
The python script boots at power up. I would like to get the python to then start the rails app. 
I have below code which works on windows.

```
os.chdir('C:\\Users\\angell\\Documents\\Rails\\RasPiServer\\')
subprocess.Popen(["thin", "start"], shell=True)
```

I have tried to run this code on the pi(with correct paths). I have tried all the examples in the python docs too, like putting the path to the app first in an array

```
args = ['/path/to/app', 'thin', 'start']
```

and passing that to the Popen

```
subprocess.Popen(args, shell=True)
```

I don't get an error, but it never opens. Works fine on windows. Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out in the end. 
I created another executable python file called startRails.py and added

```
os.chdir('/home/loubot/Documents/railsApps/RasPiServer')
os.system('pwd')
os.system('rails s')
```

This changes directory to the rails app and sends the rails s command as if it was typed in terminal. I then called this executable python script using the subprocess.Popen in my main script. This creates a subprocess that remains open

```
os.chdir('/home/loubot/Desktop/piTester')
os.system('pwd')
x = subprocess.Popen('./startRails.py')
```

When I execute my main script from the terminal now

```
./main.py
```

it opens a rails server as a subprocess and continues executing the main script.